# How to map one array to two in Ruby and perform some function if a condition is met

Tags: ruby, iterator, reduce, collect

I’m trying to improve the readability of a piece of code and also make it more concise if possible.

I have an array that needs to be iterated over and if any item matches some criteria I want to collect it and also do some other work ie updating the balance as we iterate if the if condition is met is necessary

```
need_bananas = []
need_apples = []
balance = 10

array.each do |item|
  if need_bananas?(item)
    need_bananas << item
  elsif need_apples?(item)
    need_apples << item
  end
  balance -= item.amount
end

def need_bananas?(item)
  balance >= item.amount
end 

def need_apples?(item)
  balance < item.amount
end
```

This feels too cumbersome and there must be a way to make it more concise. I have thoughts around using reduce or partition etc but I can’t settle on a nice solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use map (to create the need_banans / need_apples arrays) and sum (to calculate the balance) to make the code more readable

Comment: Please post some contextual code. This currently smacks of an X/Y problem, where you've decided *a priori* that some solution will solve your underlying problem, but it's unclear what conditions you're talking about, about why straightforward tallies or increment/decrement operations are insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that will work for you?

```rb
balance = 10
need_bananas, need_apples = array.partition do |item|
  (balance -= item.amound) >= 0
end
```